# validation instruction

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What are the ways to validate form data (in ASP.NET MVC and C#) such as input fields. I try jquery validator but failed. Are there other ways?

Comment: What do you mean, "but failed"?

Comment: I dont prevent posting data from form if any field is emty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 2.0 beta has jQuery validator integrated.  Might be worth a look.

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC 1.0 in my project

Comment: You can do it with MVC 1.0: see here http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Here are several useful tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_Validation) on ASP.NET MVC validation.

Answer (score 1):

MVC v2 has DataAnnotation Validation Support, see Scott Gu's [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx) on this topic.

Comment: You can use DataAnnotation Validation in ASP.NET MVC v1.0 as well.  http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx

Comment: how validate input field who  does not have model function

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use **MVC 2 RC**, jQuery and **jQuery.validate** plugin. How it works you can read on [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx). Please, be careful. Phil wrote article in time of MVC 2 Beta. About issues with implementation on RC you can read here: [ASP.NET MVC 2 RC client side validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997293/asp-net-mvc-2-rc-client-side-validation-not-working/2001347#2001347).

Comment: In my project I use MVC 1. In next project I will use MVC 2. Tnx