# asp.net mvc client side validation on multiple forms in one page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have 4 forms in my asp.net mvc view. I have enabled client side validation on each by put `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` Above `Html.BeginForm()` of each form. The issue is that regardless of the fact that I've specified ID's for the forms the first form on the page gets validated whenever I click submit of the other forms.

Is this usage supported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help

```
                <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => ((RegistrationFormModel)m.Data).Email, null, new { id = "registration_Email" })%>
```

Comment: that is you just specifies a custom id for the field insead of the generated one. Woks fine.

Comment: Thanks, this got me out of a bind when using the same form in a partial for both adding new data and editing existing. just added a simple check to see if the primary key was 0 (ie, new data), and added a custom id for those.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have validation messages for the properties.  Unless you have a validation message or (ValidateFor()), the property isn't added to the set of elements validated on form submission.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463967/asp-net-mvc-2-client-side-validation-rules-not-being-created) for more info.

Comment: I'm using Html.ValidationMessageFor

Comment: Client Side validation works with one form but as soon as I add more forms every time I click submit on the other forms the first form on the page will be validated.

Comment: Hmmm.  Looks like it only generates a single set of validation metadata.  You might need to use some alternate client-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

MVC2 fully supports the setup that you're looking for, my guess is that you're applying this to something like displaying a registration form and a login form on the same page?

If so you just need each form to have independent property names, i.e.

LoginModel would have a Username property and RegistrationModel would have a RegistrationUsername.

Not a great example there, but what's probably happening is that the validation is firing cross form because your properties have the same name.